# Unsupported Media type error 145 in Jmeter response

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter, trying to the rest Webservice. I am getting a Json response saying

```
  Response code: 415
  Response message: Unsupported Media Type
```

I have set the HTTP Header Manager

```
  Content-Type application/json
```

Request:

```
  Protocol HTTP
  Use KeepAlive 
  Follow Reidrects are checked.
```

This server is up and running since I am getting the proper response using Postman client.

Comment: Are you using GET or POST method?

Comment: I am using a POST method

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your request body is not a JSON format.

Maybe you mixed up parameters and body.

- Parameter must be in path after "?"
- Body must be in Body Data tab